# HttpWebResponse fails when trying to download a CSV file

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to download a CSV of historical data from the NASDAQ. The code doesn't work when I call the GetResponse method on the request. Here is the code that doesn't work:

```
string url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/A/stocks/2019-07-19/2020-07-19";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

The response never comes back and it just times out. Sometimes it gives me a 404 error. If I paste the URL into a browser, it downloads fine. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That website seems to run forever if you don't pass `Accept-Encoding` (e.g. `gzip, deflate, br`) and `Connection` (e.g. `keep-alive`) headers, based on testing with Postman.

Comment: I copy and paste your URL in browser and it gives me `access denied`! But with proxy it works. Make sure you don't use proxy in your browser.

Comment: As was said by @mjwills you need to add headers to your request. But you can't set `Connection` to `keep-alive` in `HttpWebRequest` parameters. However, I was able to get a response by setting only the `Accept-Encoding` header to your code sample. So just use `req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");`